# Azure Media Player - Version 2.0 - options and settings not being picked up when set

Tags: javascript, html, azure, azure-media-services

Today I wanted to upgrade from Azure Media Player Version 1 to the new Version 2 as mentioned here :

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/now-announcing-azure-media-player-v2-0/

It seems there is an issue when setting the options, they do not actually work even though I have set them up exactly as mentioned in the documentation, which was the same as in version 1.

See sections on "Hotkeys" and "Logo" here, pretty simple really, just set the options, then pass them in when initialising http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/index.html#amp.player.hotkeys

Here is a jsFiddle example where you can see the settings being set, but the logo in the top right is not being removed and neither is the setting which stops the scroll event managing the volume

[jsFiddle of the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/stradle/znbaqp0o/)

See the options being set here, but the logo is still showing and the volume is still being manipulated by the scroll

```
var myOptions = {
    "nativeControlsForTouch": false,
    controls: true,
    autoplay: false,
    width: "640",
    height: "400",
    hotKeys: {
        enableVolumeScroll: false
    },
    logo: {
        enabled: false
    },
}
```

Anyone managed to get this working after upgrading? Surprised I have not seen anything else about it as surely most people want rid of that logo if using this player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug that was fixed in version 2.1.2.
Make sure you reference the newer versions, at time of posting it is 2.1.5 :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/2.1.5/skins/amp-
default/azuremediaplayer.min.css">
<script src="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/2.1.5/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
```

See the changelog here:
http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/changelog.html